# Can `tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"` go along with `tools:ignore="AllowBackup"`?

Tags: android, android-manifest

As posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39178185/3286489, to solve the error as below

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processProductionDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@supportsRtl value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-36 
is also present at [com.mylibrarypackage:mylibrary:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-35 value=(true). 
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-67:19 to override.
```

We could use add `tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"` as below.

```
<application 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"/>
```

This works.

However if we have `tools:ignore="AllowBackup"` in the application tag, seems like the `tools:replace` is has not effect, and the above error persist.

```
<application 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    tools:ignore="AllowBackup"
    tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"/>
```

Is this a bug? Or I miss something?

Comment: problem for `android:allowBackup="true"`

Comment: As far as I know, we can't use both `tools:replace` and `tools:ignore`. So you might remove one from your AndroidManifest.xml declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue on their side, fixed in `I32310f1c4a1e6e8847aa14be34689c5ed406e2a7`. I haven't found the actual commit diff, if someone knows how to find those commits, please comment.

Also there are these two issues reported:

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193679
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205956

Both issues are marked as resolved. Final version of my `<application>` tag was just the `replace` stuff, I deleted all `ignore` attributes and the build passed. I now have lint (visual) warnings in Android Studio, but it's not affecting the build.