# How to add more than one `tools:replace` in Android Manifest Application?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm using a library that has the below in its Manifest.

```
<application android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"/>
```

However, as the application that I use to include the library the reverse of the setting instead

```
<application android:allowBackup="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"/>
```

Hence it would have merger error like [Is `android:supportsRtl="true"` in the Library Manifest essential? It is causing error sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39178130/is-androidsupportsrtl-true-in-the-library-manifest-essential-it-is-causing)

To solve it, we just need to add the following to our Manifest application.

```
tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
```

and

```
tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
```

However, adding two `tools:replace` will have error in compilation. How could I combine the two `tools:replace`?

I tried the below, and it's not working.

```
tools:replace="android:supportsRtl|android:allowBackup"
```

Comment: Try with comma tools:replace="android:supportsRtl,android:allowBackup"

Answer (score 383, accepted):

As per Paul's answer in the comment for the question above, use comma:

```
 tools:replace="android:supportsRtl,android:allowBackup"
```